# defmethod catch all

Tags: clojure, multimethod

I have a multimethod that specializes on two parameters:

```
(defmulti get-tag-type (fn [type tag] [type tag]))
```

Having the type allows me to group the different defmethod calls into sets:

```
(defmethod get-tag-type [::cat 0] [type tag] ::tiger)
(defmethod get-tag-type [::cat 1] [type tag] ::lion)
(defmethod get-tag-type [::cat 2] [type tag] ::jaguar)

(defmethod get-tag-type [::dog 0] [type tag] ::poodle)
(defmethod get-tag-type [::dog 1] [type tag] ::australian-shepherd)
(defmethod get-tag-type [::dog 2] [type tag] ::labrador-retriever)
```

However, sometimes, I want a catch all or default for one of the groups, which would be called if none of the others matched:

```
(defmethod get-tag-type [::dog :default] ::mutt)
```

However, this doesn't work unless `tag` is actually `:default`.

What is a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your dispatch function needs to know which mappings are already defined so that it can decide when to resort to a default.  The `methods` function will return those mappings to you.

```
(defmulti get-tag-type (fn [type tag] 
                         (let [mlist (methods get-tag-type)]
                           (if-let [d (get mlist [type tag])] 
                             [type tag]
                             [type :default]))))
```

Answer (score 8):

Multimethods support a fallback method, identified by using the (configurable) value `:default` , if none of the other methods match.

In your case, you'd simply add:

```
(defmethod get-tag-type :default [type tag]
  (do special behaviour here ...))
```

Given your example, it might be worth noting that you can establish hierarchies using Clojure keywords, and multimethod dispatch understands those hierarchies: http://clojure.org/multimethods

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the default behavior to be different for different values of type, and I believe only one `:default` can be defined per multi method.

Answer (score 0):

You could alter the defmulti to:

```
(defmulti get-tag-type (fn [type tag] 
                         (if (= type ::dog)
                             ::dog
                             [type tag])))
```

Then write your method like this:

```
(defmethod get-tag-type ::dog ::mutt)
```

Comment: I don't want the defmulti to know about the defmethods that will be using it.